# VBA question: debug.print displays the correct data - how to get it out of Immediate window?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my database I have certain tables that have confidential information. Each of these tables contains an empty field called "ThisTableIsConfidential". I have a function that correctly displays a list of the tables that have this field in the Immediate window. Now I want to display the list on a form and I can't figure out how to do it. I thought to put the function in a query and display that in a listbox but the query didn't work. Any ideas?

This is the function (I cobbled it together from a few different online sources):

```
Function GetConfidentialTable()
 Dim db As Database, tbl As TableDef, fld As Field, currentTable As String
   Set db = CurrentDb

   For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
        If (tbl.Attributes = 0) Then  

        currentTable = tbl.Name

        If FieldExists(currentTable, "ThisTableIsConfidential") = True Then
            Debug.Print currentTable
        End If
     End If

   Next tbl
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the listbox row source type to Value List and then use your function to return a list:

```
Function GetConfidentialTable()
 Dim db As Database, tbl As TableDef, fld As Field, currentTable As String
   Set db = CurrentDb

   For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
        If (tbl.Attributes = 0) Then  

        currentTable = tbl.Name

        If FieldExists(currentTable, "ThisTableIsConfidential") = True Then
            sList = sList & ";" & currentTable
        End If
     End If

   Next tbl

   GetConfidentialTable = Mid(sList,2)
End Function
```

Comment: That was it, thank you! I had to tweak your answer slightly as follows:
1. I changed sList to this: sList = sList & currentTable & vbCrLf to add a line break so that it displayed as a list rather than a long string.
2. Once I did that Access required that the element was a text box to display the entire thing rather than a list box (which only displayed the first line).
3. Also this meant I could change GetConfidentialTable = Mid(sList,2) to GetConfidentialTable = sList

Thank you for this!

Comment: @Tara If that is what suits you, but I do not think it is a good idea for the longer term. It was not necessary to change the code or to use a textbox. I think you must have missed my comment that you must set the row source type to Value list (property sheet for the listbox)

Comment: Had you made any other changes to the listbox, such as setting the number of columns? I have tested the above, and it works on a new list box with the single change of setting the Row Source Type. This is by means an unusual thing to do, and the approach is standard.

Comment: @Remou's code produces a proper string to assign as the value list of a listbox formatted with a single column.